# SSH: completly disabling password authentication

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, ssh, openssh

is there a way to disable password authentication completely? The command line is the following:

```
ssh -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no machine"
```

it STILL asks for a password.  Of course I would like to do this without touching the server, if possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay, I've found it! It's

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes host
```

Not very intuitive, especially with the fact that the options I tried previously don't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can add those option to .ssh/config and save some typing:

```
Host host
BatchMode yes
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and found the answer here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160403020906/http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/47179

Basically, openssh used keyboard-interactive to implement challenge-repsonse. So if either of these options are set to "yes", then keyboard-interactive gets set to "yes" in the code. You have to set both to "no" in order to get the behavior you want.

I had to do:

`ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no`

Of course, the `BatchMode=yes` setting would take care of all of these for you and future proof you against any new user interactive authentication methods in the future.